# Remove hyperlink from all the excel cells in a xls (MS-Interop) document using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

Does anyone know how to efficiently remove all the hyperlinks from cells in an excel document using c#? I am using MS-Interop to deal with excel documents.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.clearhyperlinks.aspx
Calling the `ClearHyperlinks()` method on the specified range is equivalent to using the Clear Hyperlinks command from the Clear drop-down list in the Editing section of the Home tab. Only hyperlinks will be removed; all other cell content, such as text and formatting will be unaffected.